# How can I locally store file field selections in the context of an offline web app?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, offline, fileapi

I am developing an HTML5 offline-enabled web app which collects several form fields and multiple files (usually images) from users. We have a need to allow these users to select photos to upload before they can actually be uploaded, perhaps while they are still offline. When they go online, the form can be submitted and files will be uploaded.

How can I save this information? The files will be too large to store directly in localStorage. Can I use localStorage to instead store some kind of reference to the file, then recall it later for upload? Can I use the application cache somehow?

Comment: If you are doing this offline then its ok but at online you can not access path which you have if you are using it globally then i think you can not do it using fileupload try some other resources

Answer (score 1):

The [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) API is for your friend.

With this, you can store the img src urls and later you can upload these images :)

Comment: Does this work between loads of the document? Your link indicates that the url returned by createObjectURL() expires when the document is unloaded. I tested and I seem to get a 404 if I close a tab and navigate back to the page and try to use an old URL. I need a reference that will persist indefinitely until the user goes online.